# Very slow Java startup in Solaris 10

Tags: java, solaris

We've got a problem on our solaris machine, as Java takes very long to start. Even on simple things as java -version

```
>time java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

real    0m34.084s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m8.331s
```

Funny enough, this is limited to Java6:

```
java version "1.5.0_24"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_24-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0_24-b02, mixed mode)

real    0m0.320s
user    0m0.123s
sys     0m0.138s
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known problem in dtrace initialisation for the jvm. Goes away in java 6u25, I believe, per Sun Alert 1296670.1. We uncovered this problem in an important environment last week, and the pain was excruciating (if you need to run 100 processes a minute, and they abruptly start taking an extra 10s to startup...).

Workaround if you are pinned to your JVM:

export DTRACE_DOF_INIT_DISABLE=true

This has been 100% successful for us, we're not using the JVM specific dtrace probes anyway.

Comment: We just hit the same problem with Solaris (5.10 Generic_144488-06 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise) and Java Version 1.6.0_24-b07 - Your answer saved the day! Funny though that the problem did not show up earlier and not on all our systems (running same OS and Java Versions)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Java 6 is installed on a network drive. Can you try

```
df `which java`
```

Comment: Nope, not a network drive, both jdk's are running on the same drive.

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
truss java -version
```

to see if it waits a long time on a particular system call.

Comment: Great idea, the last line before the long wait is: `open64("/dev/dtrace/helper", O_RDWR)  = 3` when I do a truss on Java5, this call does not appear, instead it calls `open64("/devices/pseudo/dtrace@0:helper", O_RDWR) = 3`. Sounds like a clue :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might try it with the latest java 6 update (6u27).

Comment: That is unlikely to fix the issue. Having Solaris being up to date with library patches, especially the C++ runtime one, would be a better approach.